# Extending LVM strip

Tags: lvm

I have a number of NVME Drives and what to create a lvm group and strip the data over the NVME disk to keep the ware on all the drive more even.
I am cool with this.

```
lvcreate -i 3 -n lg_group vol_group -l 100%FREE
Strip set of 3 disks.
```

My Question is.
Is it possalbe to add a 4,5,6 NVME drive and increase the strip from 3 to 4,5,6...  As you add disks.
I testing this on a VM.  Where I create 5 10G disks.
I create a strip of 3 disks.  `/dev/sd[bcd]`

```
parted --script /dev/sdb "mklabel gpt"
parted --script /dev/sdb "mkpart 'LVM2' 0% 100%"
parted --script /dev/sdb "set 1 lvm on"
parted --script /dev/sdc "mklabel gpt"
parted --script /dev/sdc "mkpart 'LVM2' 0% 100%"
parted --script /dev/sdc "set 1 lvm on"
parted --script /dev/sdd "mklabel gpt"
parted --script /dev/sdd "mkpart 'LVM2' 0% 100%"
parted --script /dev/sdd "set 1 lvm on"



parted --script /dev/sdb "mklabel gpt"
parted --script /dev/sdb "mkpart 'LVM2' 0% 100%"
parted --script /dev/sdb "set 1 lvm on"

parted --script /dev/sdc "mklabel gpt"
parted --script /dev/sdc "mkpart 'LVM2' 0% 100%"
parted --script /dev/sdc "set 1 lvm on"

parted --script /dev/sdd "mklabel gpt"
parted --script /dev/sdd "mkpart 'LVM2' 0% 100%"
parted --script /dev/sdd "set 1 lvm on"

pvcreate /dev/sd[bcd]

vgcreate vol_group /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1

lvcreate -i 3 -n lg_group vol_group -l 100%FREE

mkfs.ext4 /dev/vol_group/lg_group
e2label /dev/vol_group/lg_group store
mount -a

umount /store

parted --script /dev/sde "mklabel gpt"
parted --script /dev/sde "mkpart 'LVM2' 0% 100%"
parted --script /dev/sde "set 1 lvm on"

pvcreate /dev/sde1

vgextend vol_group /dev/sde1
```

I can see the free space

```
root@volgical:/# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vol_group
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        4
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                4
  Act PV                4
  VG Size               39.98 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              10236
  Alloc PE / Size       7677 / <29.99 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       2559 / <10.00 GiB

lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vol_group/lg_group
 Using stripesize of last segment 64.00 KiB
 Size of logical volume vol_group/lg_group unchanged from <29.99 GiB (7677 extents).
 Logical volume vol_group/lg_group successfully resized.

 e2fsck -f /dev/vol_group/lg_group
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
store: 13/1966080 files (7.7% non-contiguous), 170263/7861248 blocks

resize2fs -p /dev/vol_group/lg_group
resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
The filesystem is already 7861248 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

So I am guessing I need to do something to change the strip from 3 to 4?  Before I can get it to grow into the next disk?

```
 lvs -o+lv_layout,stripes
  LV       VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Layout     #Str
  lg_group vol_group -wi-a----- <29.99g
```

Comment: So I guess there is no answer to this.  Playing on my VM I did kinda manage to do this.  I added 4 extra disks. then extrended the the logical group into those.  And I ended up with one volume the right size.  but two strips of 4 disks each.  So I am not sure how this would work.  maybe it will fill up the 1st group before moving onto the 2nd?

Comment: pvcreate /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh1 /dev/sdi1

#
# Extran the volume group

vgextend vg_store /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh1 /dev/sdi1

# vgs
root@andy-VirtualBox:/store# vgs
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vg_store   8   1   0 wz--n- <39.97g 19.98g

# Extrend
 lvextend vg_store 
 
 lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/vg_store-lv_store
 
 # umount and mount
 umount /store

 # Resize
resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/vg_store-lv_store
# mount
mount /store

Comment: # Out come two strips???
lvs -o+lv_layout,stripes
  LV       VG       Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Layout     #Str
  lv_store vg_store -wi-ao---- <39.97g                                                     striped       4
  lv_store vg_store -wi-ao---- <39.97g                                                     striped       4